# React getting state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently creating my own mini-bbcode editor for my ReactJS application. I use functional components. In the TextEditor.jsx file I have the following code that handles the textarea.

```
const [bbcodeText, setBbcodeText] = useState("");

const update = (e) => {
    setSelection(null);
    setBbcodeText(e.target.value);
    if (typeof props.onChange == 'function') {
        props.onChange(e.target.value);
    }
}

<textarea className="form-input forum__body-input" ref={textAreaRef} value={bbcodeText} onChange={update} />
```

The above works correctly, however I installed [emoji-mart] [1](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart) to have access to the option to place emojis in the textarea, for which I use the following code:

```
const handleEmoji = (emoji) => {
        let newText = bbcodeText + " " + emoji.native;
        setBbcodeText(newText);
    }
<Picker title="Emojis" emoji="grinning" set='apple'  style={{width: '100%'}} onSelect={handleEmoji} />
```

The textarea updates correctly, the problem is that this TextEditor component accesses it from a parent component of the form:

```
 const [bbcode, setBBcode] = useState();
 const update = (v) => {
    setBBcode(v);
};


const handlePost = async() => {
    console.log(bbcode)
}
<TextEditor onChange={update}  onSelect={handleEmoji} />
<button className="button purple" onClick={handlePost}>Agregar respuesta</button>
```

The problem occurs if I select an emoji and try to access the "bbcode" state, the result is an empty string, but if I write something after it, the emoji is already shown with the text at the end, that is, I need to fire the onChange to display the updated data.

What I need to know is a guide on how to get the updated status, if I only want to insert emojis in the textarea, for example.

In this case bbcode returns undefined if I only use "emojis" but if I write text it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest moving the `onChange` callback logic to an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `bbcodeText` state. This way anything that updates the `bbcodeText` state value will trigger the effect to invoke the `onChange` handler to update anything in the parent component.

```
const [bbcodeText, setBbcodeText] = useState("");

const update = (e) => {
  setSelection(null);
  setBbcodeText(e.target.value);
}

const handleEmoji = (emoji) => {
  setBbcodeText(bbcodeText => bbcodeText + " " + emoji.native);
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof props.onChange == 'function') {
    props.onChange(bbcodeText);
  }
}, [bbcodeText]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution resolve the problem!

Comment: @AndrésCortés Ah yes, thanks for reminding me to re-review your question and my answer... TBH the details about `TextEditor` had thrown a bit of doubt to me if I'd actually understood your question/issue clearly. Great that it is resolved. Cheers.